# Importing error "from google.cloud import bigquery"

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm trying to import the google.cloud bigquery library, but I keep getting an error. The error I got:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'bigquery' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)`

```
pip install google-cloud-bigquery

pip install --upgrade google-cloud

pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery
```

I also tried these methods but still the error persists

Comment: Ensure you’re pip installing those dependencies using the same python interpreter that you’re using to import them by issuing `python -m pip install google-cloud-bigquery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using virtual environment, activate it:

```
source <your-env>/bin/activate
```

Install the BigQuery client library:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery
```

Import the library in your code:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

If it still fails, verify whether you installed and activated the correct virtual environment.

If you are using serverless services such as Cloud Run, Functions, dataflow etc, make sure to add dependencies in `requirements.txt` file with specific version:

```
google-cloud-bigquery==3.35
```

Comment: in my notebook I am getting this error, but even if I do the install from within the notebook, the error remains

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing python code in Apigee cloud function, There should be one requirements.txt file, add the below line in it

```
google-cloud-bigquery
```

then import it in python file

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
```