# Can't import module - python (unknown location)

Tags: python, google-bigquery, python-import

**EDIT**: I was able to get the modules to work by doing `import google.cloud.bigquery` instead of `from google.cloud import BigQuery` - But I am not sure why that is....

I am trying to connect to BigQuery using python for my first time ever. I looked on here for answers but I tried all answers I saw with no avail (Which my steps are show below).
Before I even test out connecting with credentials, I just wanted to make sure I can get the modules working without error.

Here are my steps:

1. `python -m venv .venv`
2. `venv/scripts/activate` (I'm on windows)
3. `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-BigQuery`

Here is the python file:
import requests
from google.cloud import BigQuery

Here is the error:

```
File "C:\Users\Jaton\Documents\Webapps\bigquery\test.py", line 2, in <module>
from google.cloud import BigQuery
ImportError: cannot import name 'BigQuery' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)
```

I also tried doing `pip install google-cloud` but that didn't work.

[image: Example]

I already tried these links:

[Importing error "from google.cloud import bigquery"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74155056/importing-error-from-google-cloud-import-bigquery/74157448)

[ImportError: cannot import name 'bigquery' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65231632/importerror-cannot-import-name-bigquery-from-google-cloud-unknown-location)

[ImportError: cannot import name 'bigquery' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location) persists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73015807/importerror-cannot-import-name-bigquery-from-google-cloud-unknown-location)

Comment: Did you execute `pip install google-cloud`?

Comment: Good idea @TuhinPaul - However I tried that and still no luck. However, I found out that if I do `import google.cloud.bigquery` it works....not sure why `from google.cloud import BigQuery` doesn't.

Comment: i see a spelling issue here: it should be `from google.cloud import bigquery`
check the python code sample here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#use

Comment: YES THAT WAS IT! If you want to make an answer, I will give you credit since you figured out why it wasn't working from the `from` statement. Thank you! (didn't know spelling matters on modules. That is something I will remember). Also this website needs to change its instructions because that is where the real problem started: https://hevodata.com/learn/connecting-bigquery-to-python/#s1

Comment: Posted the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To install the library, execute: `pip install google-cloud`
- Although
  the documentation mentions 'BigQuery', the case-sensitive spelling to
  use in the code is `bigquery` as in `from google.cloud import bigquery`

One thing annoying about python documentations in many libraries is that the internals (e.g., bigquery members above) are not specified as a list in detail (contrary to java api documentations that give specific details).